Checksum error during installation of TrueNas Core in a new machine but FreeBSD installs fine
I'm trying to install TrueNAS CORE 13.0-U6.3 on a machine and cannot get past checksum error on base-os....tgz.

Machine Spec: TRIGKEY G4 Mini PC 12th Generation Intel Alder Lake-N N95 Processor,up to 3.4GHz(4C/4T) Micro PC,Mini Computers with 16G DDR4 3200MHz/500GB PCIE1X SSD,Supports 4K@60Hz/Dual HDMI/WiFi5/BT4.

Type: x64_86, EFI

Error during install right after creating or skipping creating of swap space: See pic attached.  1


What have I tried:

Installed Win 11 in the machine successfully Installed FreeBSD 14.1
successfully Machine runs Clonezilla without issues

I'm using Ventoy to load up the ISO.

Checksum of the TrueNAS ISO is correct. I've tried safe mode install

Tried to install version 11, 12, 13 of TrueNAS core, all crash due to
a variety of reasons during bootup. Tried to install TrueNAS Scale,
it crashes as well.

However, the same flashdisk with the TrueNAS iso runs and installs on
an older machine without issues.


So what's happening here? Is TrueNAS finding some hardware issue or compatibility issue with the TrigKey Machine.[![

